# Need an Active Directory server to use stand alone DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

I have the need to add 2 AD servers to our domain but at each of these particular sites would like DNS to be stand alone (not AD integrated).  I can't say I have every tried this before as I have always made my AD servers AD Integrated DNS servers as well.  I have already built the first server and did NOT select to install DNS during DCPROMO but rather install DNS after.  It automatically integrated with DNS.  How can I remove the AD Integration piece of AD without screwing anything up?  And/or any thoughts on how to build this out?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It _is_ possible to do this, however in my experience far more trouble than its worth.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? Tell us why and perhaps we can offer another solution. Attempting to do it without an actual *need* to do so makes no sense.

Comment: We have the need for certain records to NOT replicate outside of each of these new locations because of our phone system (need to design stand alone survivability and route all SIP traffic from end points at a remote location through the main gateway at the datacenter.  By passing through the remote location first so if the Datacenter connectivity is lost a local copy of DNS is on the remote location phone 'server'. From what we are being told the answer to this in a Linux world is to create what they are calling a "DNS view" at each location.  Never hear the term before.)

Comment: but also the need for them to be on the domain, have authentication survivability, etc. if they lost their WAN link. This is hard to explain in writing what needs to be done.  Hopefully this helps.  Thanks for any input.

Comment: Please expand your explanation on your scenario. How is the SIP traffic related to your AD DNS zone exactly?

Comment: I am not too familiar with our phone sytem but from what I being told the 'server' at the remote site only performs basic PRI functinonality (which is what would be needed for this project if we had a wan outage) but now traffic comes through the corp datacenter phone server for everything so if the remote site lost WAN connectivity now they would lose all phone functionality even PRI because there is no local DNS pointing it through the local server first then the corp server.  So the local stand alone (no AD integrated DNS)is needed for local resolution.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Here is a response I had from our phone people on how this works.  When survivability is enabled and the phones in remote location A and remote location B perform a DNS SRV lookup to determine where to send their SIP traffic, the IP address returned for the phone server must be the one at the location of the phone.  So in Location A, it will be the IP address of the server in Location A and in Location B, the one in Location B.  The server keeps a table of registrations (phone IP addresses) so if the Corp office server becomes unreachable, it will handle the call routing for the local phones.

Comment: That will be for station to station calls at that location and calls to and from the PSTN.

So we need to add SRV and A records to DNS for the server in location A and B and give them weighting values so that the server receives all SIP traffic to maintain this registration table.  If the device is down, then the phone will use one of the addresses for the Corp server cluster as the destination for its SIP traffic.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the service itself where you can choose whether to integrate with AD or not - it is the zone. Basically, what you are setting there is the storage location for the zone. An AD-integrated zone is stored within the Active Directory store (more precisely within a separate partition of the LDAP directory which is part of the AD). A non-AD-integrated zone is stored in BIND-style files on the filesystem.

After you've created a zone, you simply can ***[set the type and storage location by editing its properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757440%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)***:

[image]

Note that with an AD-integrated zone setups, all your zone copies are writeable, i.e. they are all considered "primary". With a non-integrated setup, only a single zone is writeable, so only this can be updated using DNS dynamic update mechanisms. If the server holding the primary zone copy is offline, updates can no longer be performed to the zone until you designate another server as "primary".

Comment: If I have already performed a DCPROMO, installed the DNS role and it looks like your screen shot (the same settings/indicating AD integration).  What will happen if I were to uncheck the "Store the zone in Active Directory" box on the new AD server?  Wouldn't this blow up AD DNS by pulling back the DNS records of the other AD servers as they would think they are no longer AD Integrated?  Thanks!

Comment: @JBu You would have to convert all but one zone copy your DNS servers are holding to "secondary" and non-AD-integrated - this would copy the zone data out to files and change the SOA records accordingly. After that you should be able to convert the last, "primary" DNS zone to non-ad-integrated. No blowing up is necessary in the course of action.